# Perform a find and replace on thousands of Word files stored in a varbinary column of SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, ms-word

I've got a SQL Server database which has a table which contains a varbinary column.

This table has tens of thousands of rows.

This varbinary column contains documents: 85% in MS Word .doc format, 10% in .docx format and the rest in .pdf and .rtf.

There is a particular string which appears in all of these documents (an email address). I'd like to replace this string in all of these documents with a new string (an updated email address). (To be clear: The string to find and the string to replace it with is the same in all cases).

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this for all the file types but if it is only possible for .doc and .docx that would at least be the bulk of the problem solved.

I'd also like not to have to install MS Word if possible but appreciate this may be necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add the SQL query?

Comment: Not sure what SQL Query you mean? At present there is a table with a varbinary column which contains documents. I'm open to any solution which allows me to essentially perform a find and replace on the contents of those documents, replacing my old email address with my new email address within those documents. Thanks.

Comment: you must extract each file itn the file system, open it with the appropriate editor, replace the string, save it and upload the new file back into the database. This is not a task for SQL, it is not a magic pixie dust that understands every file format out there...

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: Stoleg: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Are the PDFs, you have, editable? Word of any version stores text as plaintext, and PDF doesn't. You need to research how to do search and replace in PDFs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can Convert the Value to VarBinary and then replace the value. use below link to replace the varbinary value:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=76304

Comment: Deepak, thanks for your suggestion. I've already tried doing a hex find and replace on a sample .doc file to see if that would be a solution. Unfortunately it causes the .doc file to become corrupt and no longer readable by Word. (I'm guessing this is due to some header information in the binary .doc file which is expecting a certain length of content. This is backed up by the fact that if I do a hex replace for a string of exactly the same length then this works. Unfortunately the string I actually need to replace is a different length.)

Comment: And to be clear, the documents are already stored in a varbinary column.

Comment: Since the file got corrupt, it means DB stores CRC or checksum of the file... At least you'll need to update the file and recalculate the checksum and update it too.

Comment: Stoleg, thanks for your comment. What I meant was that I attempted to perform a hex replace using a hex editor on a very simple Word document stored outside of SQL Server and this caused a corruption of the document unless I replaced the string with one of exactly the same length.     Therefore I do not think that this corruption has anything  to do with anything such a checksum being stored in the database; this issue of not being able to do a hex replace in a .doc file is completely independent of the database.

Comment: @ALT__ You need to put @ before nickname to make user notified about your response to him. When you changed Word document in hex editor: can you change to _any_ string of the same length? Copy a record aside and try same thing in DB. Filesystem and DB guard file/field consistency/length differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can be [Managing FILESTREAM Data by Using Win32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645940%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) API to get BLOB into a variable. 
This way you get contents of your BLOB in a variable and as if it was opened in Notepad. Use Replace to update .DOC, .DOCX and .RTF files. I do not know how to update PDFs.

This link contains C# code that loads BLOB into a variable in you C# code. Then you can save it with path, file name and extention derrived from DB as well. Here is a a small quote of code:

```
//Read the data from the FILESTREAM
//BLOB.
sqlFileStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);

numBytes = sqlFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

string readData = unicode.GetString(buffer);

if (numBytes != 0)
    Console.WriteLine(readData);  
//Here you have contents of your BLOB as if opened in Notepad. Use Replace to update .doc, .docx and .rtf files.

//Write the string, "EKG data." to the FILESTREAM BLOB.
//In your application this string would be replaced with
//the binary data that you want to write.

string someData = "EKG data.";
Encoding unicode = Encoding.GetEncoding(0);

sqlFileStream.Write(unicode.GetBytes(someData.ToCharArray()),
     0,
     someData.Length);
```

See also [Using FILESTREAM Storage in Client Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933877%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).